# Invalid receiver type with maps

Tags: go

I'm trying to define additional methods on a basic map https://play.golang.org/p/3BKgxVJIjP1:

```golang
type Typ struct {
    config string
}

type typeRegistry = map[string]Typ

func (r typeRegistry) Add(name string) {
    typ := Typ{
        config: "config",
    }

    r[name] = typ
}
```

Doing so fails:

```
invalid receiver type map[string]Typ (map[string]Typ is not a defined type)
```

Before refactoring the approach was similar but with a `func` instead of `Typ`:

```golang
type typeRegistry map[string]func()

func (r typeRegistry) Add(name string, factory func()) {
    r[name] = factory
}
```

This version worked. Where is the difference in defining additional methods on map-type receivers?

Comment: `type typeRegistry = map[string]Typ` is an alias to an undefined type and you [cannot declare methods for undefined types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations), just as the error states. Use `type typeRegistry map[string]Typ` instead. See: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```golang
type typeRegistry = map[string]Typ
```

Is a [type alias](https://yourbasic.org/golang/type-alias/). You cannot define methods on aliases (only on the original type--but in this case `map[string]Typ` cannot have methods on it, so you're out of luck).

What you probably want is to create a custom type, not an alias:

```golang
type typeRegistry map[string]Typ
```

Then your methods will work.

Comment: I‘ve made this mistake- custom type vs type alias- a couple of times. Easy to get wrong as a beginner.